# NHibernate 5.0 AsQueryable not working as supposed to?

Tags: nhibernate

I am testing the new NHibernate 5.0 (5.1.3) AsQueryable()

Tried that:

```
var myList = session.Load<MyObject>(1).MyList.AsQueryable()
  .Where(x => x.Prop == "123")
  .ToList();
```

I got 3 Sql Server hits (using NHibernate Profile):

```
(1) SELECT * from tblObject where Id = 1

(2) SELECT * from tblMyList where MyObjectId = 1 and Prop = '123'

(3) SELECT * from tblMyList where MyObjectId = 1
```

My understanding was that only the second SQL would be generated. Am I missing something here?

MyList mapping :

```
m.Bag(x => x.MyList, list =>
{
    list.Key(k => k.Column("Id"));
    list.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
    list.Inverse(true);
    list.Table("tblMyList");
});
```

Edit (Added some tests)

As Roman suggested me, I did some tests without debugging

```
session.Load<MyObject>(1); // No query

session.Load<MyObject>(1).MyList  // Query 1    

session.Load<MyObject>(1).MyList.AsQueryable() // Query 1 and 2
  .Where(x => x.Prop == "123")
  .ToList();
```

Comment: try `.FetchMany(x => x.MyList).AsQueryable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that `session.Load<MyObject>(1).MyList` alone doesn't lead to any queries. Otherwise it's something with you mapping (to avoid additional queries `MyObject` must be mapped as lazy).

Also if you are debugging this code - debugger might lead to unexpected initialization queries. So make sure it's not due to some breakpoint - try to run this code without debugger.

Comment: Did some tests without debugging and edited my question with then.  All mapped entities are Lazy .

Comment: I'm actually not that sure that accessing `proxyObject.MyList` is supported without object initialization (that's query 1). It depends on proxy implementation. If you override default proxy factory (via `proxyfactory.factory_class` setting) - try to remove it and check with default one. You should also check your code with latest 5.2 - I saw some proxy related changes there. But there is a chance filters are not supported for unitialized proxies.